# Why does Silex say my route can't be found?

Tags: php, redirect, routes, silex

After updating a users profile, this line should redirect me to the page to show his profile:

```
return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('user/' . $id));
```

However, I get the following error:

> RouteNotFoundException in UrlGenerator.php line 130: Unable to
>   generate a URL for the named route "user/1" as such route does not
>   exist.

And finally, this is the controller I'm trying to redirect to:

```
$app->match('/user/{id}', function (Request $request, $id) use ($app) {
    $user = new User();
    $user->find($id);

    $team = new Team();
    $team->find($user->data()->username);

    if($team->exists()){
        return $app['twig']->render('user.twig', [
            'team_data' => $team->data(),
            'user_data' => $user->data()
        ]);
    }
    else{
        return $app['twig']->render('user.twig', [
            'user_data' => $user->data()
        ]);
    }

});
```

Can anyone tell my why this error is given even though I've defined the route?

Comment: So you got an answer for your question about 6 days ago – so what did you find out? Did the answer help? If not, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$app['url_generator']->generate('user', ['id' => $id])`

Silex (or rather the URL generator) handles the parameter processing for you.